# MediaPlayer won't loop. setLooping() doesn't work

Tags: android

```
m_MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, soundFromResource);
m_MediaPlayer.setVolume(0.99f, 0.99f);
m_MediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
m_MediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(USoundPlayback.this);
m_MediaPlayer.start();
```

I've tested it like above, I've also tested it by calling `setLooping(true)` after `start()` but with no luck.

I have two `Nexus 5` phones, both with `Android 5` on them. On one, the looping works, on  the other the sound stops after one go, it won't loop.

Any ideas ?!

Comment: What does your `setOnCompletionListener` look like?

Comment: Maybe I remember incorrectly but there are some reports on differences between NuPlayer and AwesomePlayer behavior. You can see which one is in use from Developer Options settings menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently there's an issue with `Android 5` devices which use the `NuPlayer` instead of the `AwesomePlayer`.

You can check it by going in the `Developer Options`, under the `Media` section there should be `Use NuPlayer (experimental)`. I've unchecked that and it appears it's alright now.

I haven't been able to figure out how to fix this issue, so I've hacked it a bit. I've set some flags in the code and  when it enters `onCompletion`, if the user hasn't specifically stopped the sound, i restart it there. If there's anyone with a better fix, let me know and i'll update this answer.

Here's the issue: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1695

Comment: Was this ever fixed? Is there no way to tell MediaPlayer to use AwesomePlayer for your app? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a way, no. In case you find it, let us know and I'll accept your answer instead :(

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of experimentation with media player, I have found solution to this :

call

```
m_MediaPlayer.setLoopoing(true)
```

after

```
m_MediaPlayer.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue in media player.

I used the next code to fix that:

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    if (looping) {
                        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this using this workaround:

```
public static void setMpLooping(final MediaPlayer mp, final boolean isLooping) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
            || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        if (isLooping) {
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        } else {
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(null);
        }
    } else {
        mp.setLooping(isLooping);
    }
}
```

But remember, sometimes there is a delay during the transition from end to start of the track on Lollipop