# stop mediaPlayer after start viewFlipper

Tags: android

I am a beginner user of android studio, and my problem is stopping mediaPlayer after starting the viewFlipper in my activity. when the program starts, for almost one second my music plays and then it stops playing but the viewFlipper keeps running.
anyone knows about this problem, Please?

here is my only activity:

```
package com.appinapps.slideshow;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music_1);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100, 100);
        player.start();

        ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        flipper.startFlipping();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want to ask?

Comment: You are first playing music....which plays for 1 second....then it stops... and then you are flipping View flipper........if you want to stop flipping then call flipper.stopFlipping()

Comment: You want Music to run in background along with ViewFlipper?

Comment: yes, exactly! I want the music play along with the viewFlipper.

Comment: Can you help me? How can I do this?

Comment: Works fine here. Could you take a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566268/mediaplayer-wont-loop-setlooping-doesnt-work, perhaps it's a related bug. Please also note that setVolume's passed in parameters range from 0.0 to 1.0, not 0-100.

Comment: None of them helped me. I am so confused about this problem...

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because of a bug in Android Virtual Device.
After installing the application on real android device, that will be solved.